# Google Maps' scroll wheel feature doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-maps-api-3, safari

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API version 3 and in all browsers except Safari (I have version 7.0.1), the map can be zoomed in & out using the mouse wheel. I have a Logitech mouse.
Also, I'm displaying this map inside an iframe. So in Safari, its only because of iframe that the map doesn't zoom in & out using mouse wheel, otherwise it does.
Is this a known issue of Safari or is there a separate fix possible for it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved it! I simply had to add `onmousewheel="false"` attribute to the iframe.